# Ember - Missing helper action for HBS files

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have written a html with a div.

I have two hbs files. I rendered one as partial and other as normal. I am not able to invoke action on the templates. I am getting **missing helper** error.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
  <div id="holder">

  </div>
  <script src="js/libs/jquery-v1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-v1.6.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-data.js"></script>

  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
var data={title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!"};
function getTemplate(templateName,hbsPath,type){

      $.ajax({
            url: hbsPath, //ex. js/templates/mytemplate.handlebars
            cache: true
        }).done(function (src) {
            if (type === "partial") {
                Handlebars.registerPartial(templateName, $(src).html());
            } else {
                template = Handlebars.compile($(src).html());
                temp=template(data);
                $("#holder").append(temp);
            }
        });

}

getTemplate("dummy","/Test/templates/dummy.hbs","partial");
getTemplate("dummy","/Test/templates/application.hbs");


App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('dummy');
  });


App.ApplicationController=Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs:['dummy'],
  actions:{
    refresh: function(){
      alert("application template refresh");
    }
  }
});
App.DummyController=Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions:{
    refresh: function(){
      alert("dummy template refresh");
    }
  }
});
```

**HBS:**
**application.hbs:**

```
<script id="application" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{> dummy}}
</script>
```

**dummy.hbs:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='dummy'>
  <div {{action 'refresh' target="controllers.dummy"}}>
    Refresh
  </div>
  <div {{action 'refresh'}}>
    Refresh
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of {{> dummy}} try {{partial "dummy"}}

Comment: Nope "missing helper partial" error is thrown

Comment: Well reproduce ur error in emberjs.jsbin.com

Comment: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pekixehemo/1/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score 0):

The code in ur demo and the code in question are different. [**Here is a fixed demo based on the code in ur question**](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nirabi/1/edit?html,js,output).

Fixing the demo u provide may need you to include the vanilla handlebars library as ember is now using HTMLBars which is built on top of handlebars but a bit different.

Em.Handlebars.compile is now actually using HTMLBars compile method. [You can see here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-template-compiler/lib/system/compile.js#L22).

You may need to use something like https://github.com/rwjblue/broccoli-ember-inline-template-compiler

Comment: What i need is I have a list of HBS files each containing actions for its template. I want to include these templates in a HTML using ember.